# mutually exclusive events

Tags: probability

I do understand what mutually exclusive events mean (i.e. $ A \cap B = \emptyset$). But I came across this example in this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073376337)

> The following table presents probabilities for the number of times
>   that a certain computer system will crash in the course of a week. Let
>   A be the event that there are more than two crashes during the week,
>   and let B be the event that the system crashes at least once. Find a
>   sample space. Then find the subsets of the sample space that
>   correspond to the events A and B. Then find P(A) and P(B).
>
> [image]

and the author states that

> The events “3 crashes happen” and “4 crashes happen” are mutually
>   exclusive.

Why these events are mutually exclusive? If a "4 crashes happen" event happens means (to me) the "3 crashes happen" event happens for sure. Am I right?

Comment: The events: *exactly* $3$ crashes happen' and *exactly* $4$ crashes happen' are disjoint. That is what they mean here.

Comment: But there is no `exactly` in the example. Also, why they are disjoint, this is my question actually.

Comment: @CroCo:  it is implied by the meaning of the value itself.  For example, if I ask you how many times you brushed your teeth today, if you say "once," then that doesn't mean you brushed your teeth both zero times and one time.  If you say "twice," it doesn't mean you brushed your teeth once and twice simultaneously.  We do not need to use the word "exactly."

Comment: @heropup, but we here talk about how many times an even occurs. The output of this experiment is the number of crashes, so there is nothing in this example states that the events in the sample space are mutually exclusive.

Comment: The events are mutually exclusive because, as stated by @heropup, of the concept of conceiving both events. It is not a conclusion of the sample space: both events are *always* mutually exclusive, and the context or experiment or sample space or anything does not matter... the statement holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly the **number** recorded is the **count** of crashes in a week.   The tally or total number of crashes that happen.

If the *count* of crashes that happen in a week is $4$, then the *count* of crashes that happen in that week is not $3$.   They are thus mutually exclusive events.

Otherwise we would measure $100\%$ for "at least $0$", instead we have $60\%$ so it's obviously for "exactly $0$".